# How many NodeJS projects to run on a full stack Website?

Tags: mysql, node.js, web, react-fullstack

I am a beginner at the whole NodeJS Software Stack so please bear with me.

I currently have a NodeJS project that contains a Info site (with ReactJS).
I plan to extend the site to store data through mysql.

Do I need a separate NodeJS project for all the backend code? or do I just have one? This question extends to what is the proper way to architect the whole stack with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend code written in Node.js can process the data it retrieves from MySQL, there is no need for an additional project to manage it.

You will need a MySql host of some description running to connect to through.

You can look here at using MySQL with Node.js
[Link to W3 Mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp)